# issue with highChart arearange chart while adding point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I was trying to use highcharts arearange. This renders the graph but while updating chart with new points it doesn't seem to work properly. 
I tried adding points to graph with setInterval:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    chartObj.series[0].addPoint([new Date().getTime(), Math.random()*10, Math.random()*10]);
    chartObj.series[1].addPoint([new Date().getTime(), Math.random()*10, Math.random()*10]);
}, 1000);
```

Below is link for fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/saurabh0683/q808rjmt/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/saurabh0683/zcpd3Lq0/1/

Is there something wrong with code?

Comment: I think the issue is the data you are adding.  Only series 1 is arearange, so series 0 should only have 2 points in the array.  Also, your low is not guaranteed to be below your high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should add `points` only with one value to the first series, as its type is 'line'. Secondly, chart looks weird because added points of arearange and line series do not match as 'Temperature' and 'Range' series' points originally. Besides, there is a big gap in dates between the last series' points and the first added. I modified demo to be sure that the middle value is the value destined for line series and the lowest and the highest points are 
dedicated for the arearange.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/rpgqvy35/

Comment: thanks it worked. However I noticed you commented out initial values for ranges and averages assigned. Since I need to start with initial values I uncommented and applied updated values. And this still landed me in issue. May be something wrong with data or its format but tried couple of approaches like running loop at beginning then setting loop in setInterval but nothing worked. Finally I had to use one more setInterval to initiate and then cancel it.http://jsfiddle.net/saurabh0683/q808rjmt/13/.

Comment: is there some issue with hichart api or data in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/saurabh0683/q808rjmt/13/

Comment: @saurabh As I mentioned before, there is a big gap in dates between the last series' points and the first added. Last point from initial values represents 31.07.2009, while the first added indicates now (22.08.2017), so that is the reason why chart renders the way it renders. To correct this, add a new points starting from 01.08.2009. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cLc35e7c/.